# Fortran Open from current directory

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am writing a fortran program and I would like to know if it is possible to open a file from the same directory where the program itself is placed.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 BTW.

For example, if I put the compiled program at the directory "/home/username/foo" I would like the program to open the file "/home/username/foo/bar.txt" and write "Hello!" in it.

My minimal working example is the following:

```
program main

implicit none

open(unit=20,file="bar.txt",action="write")

WRITE(20,*) "Hello!"

close(20)

end program main
```

When I compile using gfortran it opens and writes in the file "/home/username/bar.txt" no matter where I put the program file.

On the other hand, when I compile it for windows (using mingw) making a .exe file and execute it in windows it does what I want, it opens the file where the executable file is placed.

[EDIT] I just found out that if I execute the program by double clicking it, it will open the file in the program directory but when I execute it from Terminal it opens at "/home/username/", so maybe is more about the way I send the command from Terminal, currently I am doing it by the following command "/home/username/foo/myprogram".

Comment: Delete the txt file, cd to a different directory, use pwd to find out where you are, run your program and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am running Ubuntu 12.04 with gfortran 4.6.3, but I do not experience this. Where ever it is that I place my executable, there is `bar.txt` after execution.

That said, if you want a file at a specific place, then declare a character string as follows:

```
character(26) :: filename
filename="/home/username/foo/bar.txt"
```

and then open the file as

```
open(unit=20, file=filename)
```

and you are home free.

**EDIT**

I just noticed your edit. I imagine that you open terminal and do not `cd` to the location of the executable, but run the command for execution. That would indeed cause you to always have the file open in whatever folder you are currently in.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast and complete answer, I cd to the location and it worked.